How to generate documentation to WinRT components generated through an .idl?
I am generating a WinRT component through an .idl file (MIDL 3.0), and more precisely I am using windows-rs. I would like documentation to be generated for the component.
I've tried the naive approach of adding /// comments above the functions signatures in the .idl, but they are aren't generated when I open the decompiled source in say, a C# project.
I could expect the consumers to look at the .idl, but it would be better if it simply shows with the signatures.
Is it possible to achieve and if yes, how?

The Windows Runtime uses WINMD files as the canonical description of interfaces and types. It repurposes .NET's ECMA-335 binary file format which doesn't have a standardized way to encode documentation. With windows-bindgen sourced from WINMDs I wouldn't expect comments to persist. Try asking for this on windows' source repository.
